# Use Content instead of Document in Umbraco (v6)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco4

I would like to update some obsolete code from umbraco v4 in the updated to v6 solution.

I have

```
entitiesFolder = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document(folderId);
entitiesFolder.ReorderChildren(
    entitiesFolder.Children.OrderBy(fdoc => fdoc.Text), 
    refreshEntireCache);
```

Now the recomendation instead of obsolete `Document` is to use `Umbraco.Core.Models.Content`. How? Didn't find (as usual for Umbraco) any documentation about... (

```
// new version
var toto = new Umbraco.Core.Models.Content(??)
toto.SoirtChildren(???)
```

Comment: Here's some documentation about the UmbracoHelper that you might find useful: [https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/)

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this from a razor view? If so you can do:

```
var nodeId = 123;
var myNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(nodeId);
var property = myNode.GetPropertyValue<string>("myStringAlias");
```

If you're doing it from a class or something you'll have to use something like:

```
var helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var nodeId = 123;
var myNode = helper.TypedContent(nodeId);
```

(This is untested but it should work..)

Comment: Thanks; The second method seems to work. What about reordering nodes? does myNode.Children.OrderBy work?

Comment: yea you could do something like: var orderedNodes = myNode.Children().OrderBy(x => x.Name); or something similar..

Comment: As in you need to reorder the nodes in the CMS programatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just querying data and need to sort it, using the `umbracoHelper` is a great way to go. It only hits the xml cache in App_Data/umbraco.config, so you don't hit the database.

However, if you are attempting to programatically sort some of the nodes in the content tree, you will need to use the `ContentService`. You will need to use the `ContentService` whenever you actually want to programatically modify content nodes. You will also find a similar `MediaService` for media.

https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService

```
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.Sort(...)
```